# Using an unique_ptr as a member of a struct

Tags: c++, reference, unique-ptr, dereference

So I have a struct like this:

```cpp
struct node {
    node_type type;
    StaticTokensContainer token_sc;
    std::unique_ptr<node> left;    // here
    std::unique_ptr<node> right;   // and here
};
```

When I tried to write a recursive function to convert a `node` to string for printing like this:

```cpp
std::string node_to_string(node n) {
    return "<other members converted to strings>" + node_to_string(*(n.left));
}
```

It gives me: `function "node::node(const node &)" (declared implicitly) cannot be referenced -- it is a deleted function`

I don't understand why this error is showing up, I had no problem when I did `(*n)` when I tried passing n as `std::unique_ptr<node>`, so I don't see why doing `*(n.left)` is not allowed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you pass `node` by value, and you cannot set one `std::unique_ptr` equal to another:

```cpp
int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<node> a = std::make_unique<node>();
    std::unique_ptr<node> b = a; //Error C2280
}
```

because who is now the *unique* owner of the data?

---

To fix your error, simple take a `const` reference in your function. This way, you pass the reference and that won't create copies:

```cpp
std::string node_to_string(const node& n) {
    return "<other members converted to strings>" + node_to_string(*(n.left));
}
```

(you should also think about exiting this function, otherwise you will get either get a stack overflow or a dereferenced nullptr, whichever comes first. For example, add `if (!n.left) return "";`)

Comment: @"Stack Danny".. Since std::string stores bytes of the string on heap, there may not be a stackOverflow? A segFault (either due to dereferencing null ptr OR invalid memory) may occur.

Answer (score 2):

The compiler error basically tells you that the copy-constructor of `struct node` is declared as **implicitly deleted**. To understand clearly what this means let's consider the following example.

```
struct node {
    node_type type;
    StaticTokensContainer token_sc;
    node* left;    // here
    node* right;   // and here
};
```

If you try the same thing with this struct declaration, you wil see that you get no error. So the problem must lie within the use of `std::unique_ptr`.

[Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor) we can see that there is written.

> The implicitly-declared or defaulted copy constructor for class T is defined as deleted if any of the following conditions are true:
>
> - T has non-static data members **that cannot be copied** (have deleted, inaccessible, or ambiguous copy constructors);
> - ...

The `std::unique_ptr` cannot be copied, as it is stated [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr)

> The class satisfies the requirements of MoveConstructible and MoveAssignable, but of neither CopyConstructible nor CopyAssignable.